# Paste clipboard as text into keyboard buffer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Once in a while I come across annoying web sites, which think they know security and won't allow me to paste password from password manager. I want a tool which allows me to take clipboard text and paste it into a web site. I know how to obtain contents of the clipboard (`xclip`), but how could I take that text and paste it in form of keystrokes?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging, and it seems that pasting could be achieved using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)

Here is a script I wrote, which could then be bound to a keystroke:

```
#!/bin/bash

XCLIP=$(which xclip)
if [ "$XCLIP" == "" ]; then
    echo "Need to install xclip"
    exit 1
fi

XDOTOOL=$(which xdotool)
if [ "$XDOTOOL" == "" ]; then
    echo "Need to install xdotool"
    exit 1
fi

TEXT=$($XCLIP -out)

if [ "$TEXT" == "" ]; then
    exit;
fi

ACTIVEWIN=$($XDOTOOL getactivewindow)
if [ "$ACTIVEWIN" == "" ]; then
    exit;
fi

$XDOTOOL type --window $ACTIVEWIN "$TEXT"
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simpler version I found elsewhere...

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool type "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'
```

The `sleep` command appears to give X enough time to switch things around, without it, it loses the first 5 or 6 characters on my system.  You might be able to lower it on some systems.

Comment: This command crashed my ubuntu 20.04...

Comment: This works perfectly, I add keyboard shortcut from Xfce setting editor

Comment: I just used this to 'type' a markdown file into Google Docs. UI was unresponsive, and it took the 5.5KB file a few minutes to be entered, but solved my challenge perfectly.

Comment: Used a variation of this: `sh -c 'sleep 5.0; xdotool type --delay 50 "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'` The added delay didn't make my browser crash

Answer (score 0):

No reputation enough to comment on "Warrentheo" and "GammaGames". Thank you for this clever line.
Additionally, inside ~/.bashrc I created this alias:

```
alias ctlv="sh -c 'sleep 5.0; xdotool type --delay 50 \"\$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)\"'"
```

Reload ~/.bashrc

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Use it

```
$ ctlv
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Although you may still lack the reputation for commenting, you may want to submit an edit suggestion to @Warrentheo's answer that includes your improvements.